# h2 in-memory tables, remote connection

Tags: database, jdbc, embedded-database, h2

I am having problems with creating an in memory table, using H2 database, and accessing it outside of the JVM it is created and running in.

The documentation structures the url as `jdbc:h2:tcp://<host>/mem:<databasename>`

I've tried many combinations, but simply cannot get the remote connection to work. Is this feature working, can anyone give me the details of how they used this.

Comment: Would be good if you listed the combinations you tried.

Comment: Do you have a problem with setting up the server (to listen on some TCP port) or the client (to connect to the server)?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528160/remote-connection-to-a-h2-database-in-server-mode-with-dbcp-pooling. It mentions `-tcpAllowOthers` switch for being visible not only at `localhost`.

Answer (score 21):

None of the solutions mentioned so far worked for me. Remote part just couldn't connect.

According to H2's [official documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases):

> To access an in-memory database from another process or from another computer, **you need to start a TCP server in the same process as the in-memory database was created**. The other processes then need to access the database over TCP/IP or TLS, using a database URL such as: jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1.

I marked the crucial part of the text in bold.

And I found a working solution at this guy's [blog](https://jsoftbiz.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/share-an-h2-in-memory-database-among-several-jvms/):

> The first process is going to create the DB, with the following URL:
>
> `jdbc:h2:mem:db1`
>
> and it’s going to need to start a tcp Server:
>
> `org.h2.tools.Server server = org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer().start();`
>
> The other processes can then access your DB by using the following URL:
>
> `"jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1"`

And that is it! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Your answer poses an interesting question: without the `createTcpServer()` call, is the H2 database run in-process, just like a SQLite database ? That would explain H2 speed, that's larger even than SQLite's speed.

Comment: I had to use `jdbc:h2:mem:db1;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to prevent `Database "mem:test" not found, either pre-create it or allow remote database creation` on the TCP connection.

Answer (score 13):

You might look at [*In-Memory Databases*](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases). For a network connection, you need a host and database name. It looks like you want one of these:

```
jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/mem:db1
jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1/mem:db1
```

Complete examples may be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5226353/230513), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34742409/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24592754/230513); related examples are examined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5225700/230513).

Answer (score 3):

Having just faced this problem I found I needed to append `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the JDBC URL for the *tcp connection*.  So my URLs were:

- In Memory : `jdbc:h2:mem:dbname`
- TCP Connection : `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/dbname;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1`

[From the h2 docs](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases):

> By default, closing the last connection to a database closes the
>   database. For an in-memory database, this means the content is lost.
>   To keep the database open, add `;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` to the database
>   URL.

Not including `DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1` means that I cannot connect to the correct database via TCP.  The connection is made, but it uses a different version to the one created in-memory (validated by using the `IFEXISTS=true` parameter)

Comment: I think DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1 should be on the in-memory connection string, rather than the TCP connection string, so that the command that creates the db is responsible for controlling its lifetime. Ideally the external connection should be ignorant of H2's implementation details and should simply ask for data

Comment: It's been quite a while since I've used H2, but the rest of my answer would indicate I meant the TCP connection

Answer (score 0):

In SpringBoot: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-access-h2-database-multiple-apps

```
@Bean(initMethod = "start", destroyMethod = "stop")
public Server inMemoryH2DatabaseaServer() throws SQLException {
    return Server.createTcpServer(
      "-tcp", "-tcpAllowOthers", "-tcpPort", "9090");
}
```