# Remote connection to a H2 database in server mode with DBCP pooling

Tags: h2, apache-commons-dbcp

I'm trying to create an embedded H2 server which I could also access remotly and also use Tomcat DBCP Pooling.

Here is my code to produce the dataSource :

```java
@Produces @ApplicationScoped
public DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException, SQLException {
    dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource");
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:/tmp/myapp");
    dataSource.setUsername("sa");
    dataSource.setPassword("");
    dataSource.setMaxActive(100);
    dataSource.setMaxIdle(30);
    dataSource.setMaxWait(10000);
    // start the pool
    Connection connection = dataSource.getConnection();
    // start the server
    server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
    connection.close();
    return dataSource;
}
```

And when I try to connect it remotly (using for example H2 Browser (`java -jar h2.jar -browser`)) using URL "jdbc:h2:tcp://192.168.2.58//tmp/myapp" (192.168.2.58 is the remote IP of the server) here is the error I get :

```
Database may be already in use: "/tmp/myapp.mv.db". Possible solutions: close all other connection(s); use the server mode [90020-179] 90020/90020
```

Does somebody have a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is finally the code that worked:

```java
@ApplicationScoped
public class DataSourceProducer {

    private JdbcDataSource dataSource;
    private Server server;

    @Produces @ApplicationScoped
    public DataSource getDataSource() throws NamingException, SQLException {
        dataSource = new JdbcDataSource();
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:h2:/tmp/myapp");
        dataSource.setUser("sa");
        dataSource.setPassword("");
        // start the server
        server = Server.createTcpServer("-tcpAllowOthers").start();
        return dataSource;
    }

    public void disposeDataSource(@Disposes DataSource dataSource) throws SQLException {
        server.stop();
    }
}
```

And then I can access it via using URL `jdbc:h2:tcp://<remote ip>//tmp/myapp` (at least I made it working via SSH tunneling the 9020 port and access it with `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost//tmp/myapp`)

Answer (score 0):

Check [H2 Multiple connections](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#multiple_connections). You need a client/server mode to be able to open the database multiple of times. By default, embedded databases cannot be opened several times. You need to use the "automatic mixed-mode" feature :

[Mixed Mode for H2 database](http://h2database.com/html/features.html#auto_mixed_mode)

So if you modify your jdbc url as follow, it should work :

jdbc:h2:/tmp/myapp;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE

Comment: The problem with mixed mode is that it cannot be accessed remotely and I want to access it from another computer. Moreover I'm already serving it as a client/server mode as I create a TCP server... but perhaps that's the embedded connection I first use which locks the DB...

Comment: I read a bit more carefully your code. You create a connection to an embedded database (because of the jdbc url) then create a server. When you call the server remotely, the first connection prevent it to access the database. Try to start the server first, then create you connection with the jdbc url : "jdbc:h2:tcp://127.0.0.1//tmp/myapp" and then try to connect remotly

Comment: I think that would work. But I wouldn't be in "embedded mode" anymore inside my web application => it would be a little less optimized...

Comment: Well, you cannot have embedded database and be able to open it multiple of times. The only alternative is to have your embedded database and offer services to query it remotely.