# How to get remote access to h2 database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbc, h2

So, I have a local server and remote server.

```
spring:
    datasource:
        driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
        url: jdbc:h2:mem:mydb;MODE=PostgreSQL;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
        username: root
        password:

    jpa:
        properties:
            hibernate:
                dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
        hibernate:
            ddl-auto: create-drop
    flyway:
        enabled: false
    h2:
        console:
            enabled: true
            settings:
                web-allow-others: true
```

How I can to connect via h2-console to remote server like in localhost?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remote connection to a H2 database in server mode with DBCP pooling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24528160/remote-connection-to-a-h2-database-in-server-mode-with-dbcp-pooling)

Comment: But I don't need multi h2 servers on a local machine, but one on a remote machine

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256295/how-to-access-in-memory-h2-database-of-one-spring-boot-application-from-another